# Keras Graph disconnected , multiple inputs embedding

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

This is a model that I am trying to build:
a model that has 4 inputs which embed them and put it into score out put

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
H = keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="H") 
R = keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="R") 
T = keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="T") 
N = keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="N") 

embedding = keras.layers.Embedding(10000, 100)
embedding_r = keras.layers.Embedding(1000, 100)

H = embedding(H)
R = embedding_r(R)
T = embedding(T)
N = embedding(N)

H = keras.layers.Flatten()(H)
R = keras.layers.Flatten()(R)
T = keras.layers.Flatten()(T)
N = keras.layers.Flatten()(N)

H_plus_R = keras.layers.Concatenate()([H, R])
T_plus_N = keras.layers.Concatenate()([N, T])

H_plus_R = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(H_plus_R)
T_plus_N = keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(T_plus_N)

score = keras.layers.Concatenate()([T_plus_N,H_plus_R])
score = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(score)

model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=[H,R,T,N],
    outputs=score,
)

model.summary()
```

And I get this which means input and output are not connected, but they are:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-90804bccaf4f> in <module>()
     32 model = tf.keras.Model(
     33     inputs=[H,R,T,N],
---> 34     outputs=score,
     35 )
     36 

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
    929                              'The following previous layers '
    930                              'were accessed without issue: ' +
--> 931                              str(layers_with_complete_input))
    932         for x in nest.flatten(node.outputs):
    933           computable_tensors.add(id(x))

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("R_7:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32) at layer "embedding_13". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After embedding your inputs, you override `H`, `R`, `T` and `N`, try using other variable names

Comment: Thanks, can you explain? because its look like everything is fine and you can send variable to layer and get it with the same name.

Comment: You declare your inputs as being the variables `H`, `R`, `T` and `N`, but redeclaring it afterwards doesn't make it the input layers anymore. In their final states, those variables represent flattening layers and not your inputs. As your network expects a certain input shape for the flattening layers, the code breaks as you send tensors with a different shape to them (i.e. the `Input` input shape).